# Easy Admin Bundle. Trix Editor. Change wrapper tags of code sections. <pre> -> <pre><code>

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I'm using the Easy Admin Bundle for a mini Symfony app. 
The bundle comes with the [trix editor](https://trix-editor.org/) for the text_editor field input.
The editor is pretty cool and offers a `code` feature that encapsulates the paragraph in `<pre>` tags. The issue is I'm using [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) on frontend to make my code sections pretty. Now **highlightjs** requires code be encapsulated in `<pre><code> ...code here... </code></pre>` tags which is a bummer.

Is there any way to control in which tags are `code` sections encapsulated with the **trix editor**. In my specific case from `<pre>` to `<pre><code>`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to update the Trix source code to add the code element in the pre element and also add the class. I asked the question [here](https://github.com/basecamp/trix/pull/715#issuecomment-569099550), and I'm going to open an issue to see if the nice folks over at Trix would consider adding this functionality.

So, I put together a little hack that will transform the pre elements when I display them to the user. Here is what the code looks like:

```
const applyFormattingToPreBlocks = function () {
  const preElements = this.showPostBody.querySelector('.trix-content').querySelectorAll('pre');
  preElements.forEach(function(preElement) {
    const regex = /(?!lang\-\\w\*)lang-\w*\W*/gm;
    const codeElement = document.createElement('code'); 
    if (preElement.childNodes.length > 1) {
      console.error('<pre> element contained nested inline elements (probably styling) and could not be processed. Please remove them and try again.')
    }
    let preElementTextNode = preElement.removeChild(preElement.firstChild);
    let language = preElementTextNode.textContent.match(regex);
    if (language) {
      language = language[0].toString().trim();
      preElementTextNode.textContent = preElementTextNode.textContent.replace(language, '');
      codeElement.classList.add(language, 'line-numbers');
    }
    codeElement.append(preElementTextNode)
    preElement.append(codeElement)
  })
};
```

I also wrote up a [blog post](https://www.bigdumbweb.dev/posts/how-to-highlight-code-blocks-using-the-trix-editor-in-rails) that goes into more detail about what this code is doing. I using Rails 6 and the post has an example of what the formatting looks like. Let me know if you have questions.